# xUnit skips tests with "could not find dependent assembly" warning

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xunit

After updating an assembly, my xUnit tests fail to run.

My project was using `System.Web.Http` version 5.2.3. I replaced this using Nuget with a fork of `System.Web.Http` version 5.2.4. Inspecting the reference shows the correct path to the new DLL.

When I run xUnit, it discovers the tests, but gives me the following warning:

```
[11/04/2018 10:43:30 AM Warning] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.9421698] Skipping: API.IntegrationTests (could not find dependent assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.4')
```

It then skips all tests.

I'm at a loss. Any help is very appreciated.